# Tableau - Aggregate and non aggregate error for divide forumla

Tags: oracle, tableau-api

I used COUNT (CUST_ID) as measure value to come up [Total No of Customer]. When I created new measure for [Average Profit per customer] by formula - [Total Profit] / [Total No of Customer], the error of Aggregate and non aggregate error prompted.

DB level:

Cust ID_____Profit

123_______100

234_______500

345_______350

567_______505

Answer (score 0):

You must be looking for `avg` aggregate function.

```
Select cust_id, avg(profit)
From your_table
Group by cust_id;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

In your database table, you appear to have one data row per customer. Customer ID is serving as a unique primary key. The level of detail (or granularity) of the database table is the customer.

Given that, the simplest solution to your question is to display AVG([Profit]) -- without having [Cust ID] in the view (i.e. not on any shelf)

If the assumptions mentioned above are not correct, then you may need to employ other methods depending on how you define your question. I suggest making sure you understand what COUNT() actually does compared to COUNTD(). The behavior is not what people tend to assume. LOD calculations may prove useful. All described in the online help.

Answer (score 0):

Put the calculations directly in the calculated field as:

```
SUM([Profit])/COUNT([CUST_ID])
```

This will give you aggregate and aggregate calculation.

If you want to show Average profit using a key like [CUST_ID], you can use LOD expression:

```
{FIXED [CUST_ID]: AVG[Profit]}
```